# EMR serverless - S3 access denied for logs

Tags: emr-serverless

I am trying to run EMR Serverless job and upload logs into S3 with following logs configuration

```
--configuration-overrides '{
    "monitoringConfiguration": {
        "s3MonitoringConfiguration": {
            "logUri": "s3://mgosk-temp/emr-serverless-spark/",
            "encryptionKeyArn" : "arn:aws:kms:eu-north-1:0000000:key/abcd"
        }
    }
}'
```

I am getting following error.

```
Unable to push logs, please ensure logging destination is valid and execution role has sufficient permissions. Error: "Failed to upload job metadata to mgosk-temp/emr-serverless-spark/applications/.../jobs/.../job-metadata.log: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied".
```

The execution role have access rights to S3 and KMS assigned , but still looks like the issue with IAM permissions. Which role is used for logs upload `execution role` or
`service-linked roles for EMR Serverless` ?

Answer (score 1):

As of now, EMR Serverless doesn't encrypt the `job-metadata.log` file even though `encryptionKeyArn` is specified, meaning the headers (eg. s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption) aren't specified. This can therefore cause `AccessDenied` issue for this file if bucket policy or Organization policy (SCP) have Deny statement based on S3 encryption headers. A workaround until EMR Serverless addresses it, would be to not restrict `s3:PutObject` request based on encryption headers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by setting up gateway endpoints for Amazon S3 and linked to EMR servereless application's subnet router.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on WendyJW's explanation, S3 Vpc endpoint should be attached to subnet route table.

1. create vpc endpoint. servicename: com.amazonaws.ap-northeast-2.s3
2. (create and) add route table to vpe endpoint step 1 created.
3. route table subnet associate emr serverless private subnet
   i have a similar issue, after set vpc endpoint and subnet associate, log write well!

- please check more information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/EMR-Serverless-UserGuide/vpc-access.html#vpc-create-app